# Closing port 22 after changing ssh port to new custom port?

Tags: ssh, port

I created a new server and changed the ssh port to a new custom port. Everything works as expected. I went through multiple guides and all of them stopped after opening the new port. My question is:

**Can I close port 22 after I changed the ssh port to a new one? Are there any disadvantages when I close it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I close port 22 after I changed the ssh port to a new one?

Yes, that's probably *the entire point* of those guides.

> Are there any disadvantages when I close it?

You will always need to specify the new custom port whenever making SSH connections to that server.

In some cases, highly-restricted networks (libraries, hotels, etc.) might disallow connections on unrecognized ports while they still allow SSH on its regular port 22. (But there might be the opposite situation, too.)